# How can I use variables as part of my bucket path with s3 boto client?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

At the moment Im trying to upload to a bucket with the variables as the path name using the boto s3 client and here are the variables I have defined:

```
var1 = A
var2 = B
var3 = C
```

I am uploading to the bucket like this:

```
client.upload_file('myfile.jpeg', 'bucket', 'directory/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}')
```

However the lambda function I am using is actually creating the variables as part of the file path. How can I actually use the values of var1,var2 and var3? My expected output is this:

```
directory/A/B/C
```

and my current output is this:

```
directory/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use f-strings? `f'directory/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python's f strings:

```py
client.upload_file('myfile.jpeg', 'bucket', f'directory/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}')
```